# Custom Edit Form with People Pickers

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I am creating a custom edit form for SharePoint built with the office-ui-fabric-react library. I recently added a people picker to my edit form and realized that lookup columns do not return on a normal "get" REST call. It seems like you have to do a select and expand for each people picker.

The get request that I had previously set up was intended to be as reusable as possible by automatically calling the list name and current item ID. At this point, I feel like I am doing something the hard way and wanted to see if anyone else had experience with people picker columns in a React SharePoint edit form.

My current workflow of setting the column values is as follows.

1. Edit form componentDidMount kicks of a get request for all current column values
2. The loaded values are set to the state
3. The child components on the Edit form are sending this.state.loadedValues down as a prop value
4. Within the child component, the value is set to this.props.value

It currently seems like if I wanted to populate my React components with current values, I would have to first do my normal "get" REST call for the usual columns, and then a separate REST call and do a select and expand for each people picker I add to my form. Is there a better way of doing this?

Here is the generic get request that I have:

```
let req = new XMLHttpRequest;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            req.open('GET', `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('${LIST_NAME}')/Items(${ITEM_ID})`, true);
            req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
            req.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');

            req.onload = async () => {
                // alert(req.status);
                if (req.status === 200) {
                    let response = JSON.parse(req.response);
                    resolve(response.d);
                } else {
                    reject(Error(req.statusText));
                }
            };
            req.onerror = () => {
                console.log(`Error: ${req.status}`);
                reject(Error('Network Error'));
            };
            req.send(null);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I made something like that, and I used one single REST Call to get all the info, expanded columns included. You only need to expand the lookups, the others columns work seamlessly.

Something like `"Id, Title, PeopleField1/Id, PeopleField1/Title, PeopleField1/EMail, FieldX, FieldY"` for the columns, and only `"PeopleField1"` for the expand.